# Ошибка при запуске кода python в Debian11

Tags: python-3.x, debian, idle

Помогите начинающему. Работаю в Debian 11. Установлен pyperclip-1.8.2 запускаю в консоли sudo IDLE. Далее набираю код (код ниже). Сохраняю файл под именем 1.py. При запуске кода для мониторинга буфера обмена выходит ошибка:
**«Traceback (most recent call last):
File «/home/debian/Рабочий стол/1.py», line 7, in 
s = pyperclip.paste()
File «/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyperclip/**init**.py», line 681, in lazy_load_stub_paste
return paste()
File «/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyperclip/**init**.py», line 301, in paste_klipper
assert len(clipboardContents) > 0
AssertionError'»**

В командной строке пишет «Service ‘org.kde.klipper’ does not exist.». .

Сам код:

```
import pyperclip

import time

old = ''

while True:

s = pyperclip.paste()

if(s != old):

    print(s)
    old = s
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Команда **sudo apt-get install xclip** решила все проблемы.